# ¿Como convertir un char* a un String^ en Visual C++?

Tags: c++, punteros, visual

Intento asignar un char * a un string^ pero me sale este error:
Error   C2440   'inicializando': no se puede realizar la conversión de 'char *' a 'System::String ^'    Compiladores    C:\Users\Manuel\Compiladores\Compiladores\Compiladores\MyForm.cpp   83

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que aprendas a plantear una buena pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir una variable de tipo char a una variable de tipo string, usaría la función `push_back()` la cual va agregar el carácter al final de la cadena.

```
char c = 'c';
string s;
    
s.push_back(c);
```